# Count all files without using find

Tags: command-line, grep

How can I count all files without using `find` and only `grep`? I tried using `ls` recursively but how can I pipe that to `grep` and count files?

Comment: Why do you refuse to use `find`? [Parsing the `ls` output is bad.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 6):

To list all files that match a grep pattern:

```
grep -rl your_regex_pattern /my/dir /my/other_dir /my/file
```

To count them:

```
grep -rl your_regex_pattern /my/dir /my/other_dir /my/file  | wc -l
```

To count all non-empty files in a directory recursively, you search for an empty string (two single quotes):

```
grep -rl '' /my/dir       | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use solely `grep` therefore you can do:

```
grep -lR ^ . | grep -c ^
```

Comment: Does not count empty files; my answer matches them neither.

Comment: Yes @kubanczyk your answer (`grep -rl '' /my/dir`) is the same as mine (`grep -lR ^ /my/dir`): the two answers ignore empty files :-(   Let's say this is a **feature** ;-)   Maybe @Marios do not want to count the empty files... NB: he said "only `grep`"

Comment: Yup. Your `grep -c` fits the requirement much better, that's why I've upvoted it :)

Comment: @kubanczyk Your answer is more pedagogical ;-)   What a pity Marios does not respond :-(

Comment: Please @Marios can you check the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
du -ah | wc -l

[and then subtract 1]
```

Comment: `du -h` lists directories only, not files.

Comment: Fine, du -ah | wc -l

Comment: Afaik, this prints the same file only once, I.e. ignores additional hard links.